# ffmpegVideo plugin cant play video

Tags: cmake, c++17, runtime-error

when i start to play my command. i see first frame of video and then getting an error which like cant find the "object". my projet is CMake C++ project. error message is this

[INFO] gObject: received audio
Stack trace (most recent call last):
#0    Object "", at 00007FF9B9339E4E, in ZN8backward14StackTraceImplINS_10system_tag11windows_tagEE9loadhereEyPvS4

i tried to play a .mp4 video at windows 10 home single. why i write this bcos at win10 pro pc it working perfectly. i installed all .NET, C++ and directx frameworks.